# NPM evaluation maintenance

Tags: npm

I've released several times already with quite a few commits but npms.io is not picking it up.

https://api.npms.io/v2/package/openweathermap-ts

```
"maintenance": {
  "releasesFrequency": 1,
  "commitsFrequency": 0,
  "openIssues": 0,
  "issuesDistribution": 0
}
```

Anyone know why it's doing that?